# Express backend server not serving all files in react front end production environment but works locally

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, react-router

I have a project using a node js express back-end (run on port 5000) and a ReactJS front end (run on port 3000) in the same project. I am able to run these projects a the same time locally with no issues (using npm start for client and nodemon index.js for server). I am also able to use 'npm run build' and serve the static files on http://localhost:3000 with no issues in the production build.

However, when I publish these changes to Azure via the 'Azure app services" extension in VS Code - I am able to authenticate the user upon login and then only the home directory works correctly. If I try to access another page, I get a 401 unauthorized error and I am not sure why.

Project file structure:

```
 - MyApp:
   - .vscode
   - Client:
      - build
         - static
            - css
            - js
         - index.html
      - node_modules
      - public
      - src
      - package.json
      - package-lock.json
   - config
   - controllers
   - middleware
   - models
   - index.js
   - package.json
   - package-lock.json
```

Client-->src-->App.js (client side routes)

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      
      <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
        {/* Public routes*/}
        <Route exact path='Login' element={<Login/>}  />
        <Route path="unauthorized" element={<Unauthorized />} />
        <Route path="invalidinvite" element={<InvalidInvite />} />
        <Route path='Application' element={<Application />}  />
        

        {/* Protected routes*/}

        <Route element={ <PersistLogin /> }>
          <Route element={<RequireAuth allowedRoles={[1, 2]}/>}> 
            <Route exact path="/" element={<Invite/>} />
          </Route>

          <Route element={<RequireAuth allowedRoles={[1, 2]}/>}> 
            <Route exact path='Submitted' element={<Submitted/>} />
          </Route>

          <Route element={<RequireAuth allowedRoles={[1, 3]}/>}> 
            <Route exact path='Approved' element={<Approved/>} />
          </Route>
        </Route>

        {/* Catch all*/}
        <Route path="*" element={Error} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

Client-->src-->index.js:

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <AuthProvider>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/*" element={<App />} />
        </Routes>
      </AuthProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

index.js (server):

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

const sequelize = require("./config/database");

const verifyJWT = require('./middleware/verifyJWT');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const credentials = require('./middleware/credentials');
const corsOptions = require('./config/corsOptions');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;


//Applying middleware
app.use(credentials); //Handle options credentials check before CORS and fetch cookies credential requirement
app.use(cors(corsOptions)); //Cross origin resource sharing
app.use(express.json()); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'build')));

//public routes
app.use('/auth', require('./routes/authRoutes'))
app.use('/postInviteId', require('./routes/postInviteId'))
app.use('/invites/:Id', require('./routes/inviteById'))
app.use('/application', require('./routes/postApplication'))

app.use(verifyJWT); //Anything below this has to have a verified JWT

//private routes
app.use('/invites', require('./routes/invites'))
app.use('/email', require('./routes/emails'))
app.use('/application', require('./routes/applications'))


app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
});

sequelize.sync().then(() => {
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Network tab when attempting to navigate to a different page (in production):

[image]

Network tab when attempting to navigate to a different page (in localhost environment):
[image]

I have unfortunately been stuck on this one for a while now and would appreciate any input.

Comment: How do you authorize the user?

Comment: @Konrad Using JWT access tokens as well as a refresh token. I then have a persist login component which verifies the refresh token to keep the user logged in

Comment: Do you use cookies to store the token?

Comment: @Konrad Yes. In the loginController.js I have the following line of code: 
```
res.cookie('jwt', refreshToken, { httpOnly: true, secure: true, sameSite: 'None', maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000}); 

```